# Bar chart requires me to click to update - is there a way around?

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a bar chart which shows a graphical representation of a building.

It has been conditionally formatted for when a cost as been placed against a floor - the floor is highlighted red on the bar chart.

I have then found a VBA which when the colour of the cell which was conditionally formatted changes colour, it changes the colour of the bar chart series to red or grey. (My coding knowledge is very limited and is something I'm looking to develop on)

However, when I add the cost, it doesn't automatically change the bar chart. It requires me to click on the chart and then it updates and turns red.

Is there a way around this with code so that when the cost is added it will immediately change the floor to red?

I have looked online for some refresh options / calculate options however my knowledge isn't the best and I may not be adding it in correctly?

Code starts here;

```
Sub CellColorsToChart()

    'Updateby Extendoffice

    Dim xChart As Chart
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim xRowsOrCols As Long, xSCount As Long
    Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
    On Error Resume Next

    Set xChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Euston Tower").Chart
    If xChart Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    xSCount = xChart.SeriesCollection.Count

    For I = 1 To xSCount
        J = 1
        With xChart.SeriesCollection(I)
            Set xRg = ActiveSheet.Range(Split(Split(.Formula, ",")(2), "!")(1))

            If xSCount > 4 Then
                xRowsOrCols = xRg.Columns.Count
            Else
                xRowsOrCols = xRg.Rows.Count
            End If

            For Each xCell In xRg
                .Points(J).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ThisWorkbook.Colors(xCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex)
                .Points(J).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = ThisWorkbook.Colors(xCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex)
                J = J + 1
            Next
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

I was putting the calculate/refresh after the J = J + 1, however that wasn't working.

Comment: Nothing in that code requires you to select the chart, so I suspect the issue is actually in how you are triggering this code.

Comment: @Rory - Thank you for your reply. Is the section;
"Set xChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObject("Euston Tower").Chart"
Where the chart is selected? The chart is called Euston Tower

Comment: That doesn't require you to select the chart. How are you running this code?

Comment: why don't you use `Chart. Refresh`

Comment: @Rory I had right clicked on the chart and then assigned the macro - is this wrong?

Comment: @Dorian Where would I add this? - sorry to sound so stupid

Comment: If you assign that as a macro to the chart, then yes you will have to click it. To get it to run automatically when the cost is added, you'll have to give more information as to how and where that occurs. In all likelihood you'll want a `worksheet_change` or `worksheet_calculate` event.

Comment: @JackLewis Hope this answer helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the value with your **hand** you will have to use `Worksheet_Change`

You need to put this code in `Sheet` and not a module :

[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range) 
  Call CellColorsToChart
End Sub
```

Else if the value are changed **by calculation** you would have to use `Worksheet_Calculate`

like below

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate() 
 Call CellColorsToChart
End Sub
```

If you only want to refresh the chart on change I would suggest you to use `.refresh`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)       
  ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Euston Tower").Chart.Refresh
End Sub
```

Do not hesitate to leave me **feedbacks** so I can improve my answer if needed

Comment: Perhaps also give the `Worksheet_Calculate()` option depending on how the sheet is updated.

Comment: He said that he add himself the value, but I will add the other way

Comment: @Dorian Thanks for the information I have inputted the .Refresh option you mentioned above and this has not worked.

Comment: @JackLewis Then use the second one which call your sub

Comment: @JackLewis if your sub was working it should work if you change value with your hand, if formula make value change you will have to use Worksheet calculate

Comment: @Dorian, done works perfectly - thanks for your help and thanks to everyone else for taking time out to look!

Comment: @JackLewis Glad that I could help you